# Change Kendo Calender Culture not working

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I am trying to change the default culture for the kendo calender to "ar-SA" 
[I am using MVC Rapper]
i did the following :

1-  I added

```
<globalization culture="ar-SA" uiCulture="ar-SA" />
```

in web.conf

2- i added

```
kendo.culture('ar-SA');
```

in document.ready

3- in the view i added template to my date column like the following :

```
columns.Bound(e => e.StartDate).Title("StartDate).Template(@<text></text>).ClientTemplate("#=kendo.toString(StartDate,'yyyy-MM-dd')#");
```

4- i added default value to date column in model

```
 model.Field(e => e.StartDate).DefaultValue(DateTime.Today.ToLocalTime());
```

but it's not working.

What i am missing here ?

Answer (score 0):

are you setting the culture client script?

According to http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/getting-started/using-kendo-with/aspnet-mvc/globalization you have to set the culture after the culture script is loaded.

Comment: You mean adding the culture script to the view, I already did this